# A most efficient way to add only new rows to a table in MSSQL and Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a MSSQL table of entities that looks like

```
IdMarker Property1 Property2 ...
411       AAA      BBB
567       CCC      DDD
...
```

I need to store in this table only unique `IdMarkers`. What would be the most performant way to add new entries from a quite large set, however, only adding entries with `IdMarker` values that are not yet present in the table, using Entity Framework Core (in short, I would like to achieve behaviour similar to what  `REPLACE` does in MySQL dialect)?

Comment: Huh? You tagged this with sql server but you want an answer in MySql? And not even really sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to add these rows to the table? What does "only adding entries with non-existend IdMarker" mean?

Comment: @SeanLange would you read the question again please. I need to work with MSSQL and require the behaviour that is the same as REPLACE operator in MySQL. I however corrected for better readability, but I urge to read carefully before adding negative ratings.

Comment: I did read carefully, more than once, and it made no sense. But the downvote was not me. I don't just downvote questions without at least giving the OP a chance to make something more clear.

Comment: Does it make more sense now?

Comment: I don't understand what REPLACE has to do with this situation. If you want to insert a number of rows that don't exist in the table, you should look into NOT EXISTS.

Comment: @AskarIbragimov if you want performance, *don't* use any ORM. In this case, there are no entities involved at all, so using an ORM will only waste time. The typical way to do this is to do a LEFT JOIN between source and target tables. If the data comes from an external source, import it into a staging table, then use LEFT JOIN to find only the new records.

Comment: @AskarIbragimov for updates of existing rows, use an INNER JOIN. You could also use [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to do both steps at once *BUT* that statement isn't atomic. You'd have to wrap it in a transaction

Comment: @AskarIbragimov to import data from a client into a staging table use SqlBulkCopy to insert the data using the bulk import mechanism and minimal logging. For N rows, this could end up being N times faster than individual inserts

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you are right, I am not a fan of ORMs at all, unfortunately I do not own the stack and need to use EF. :)

Comment: @AskarIbragimov this isn't a matter of preference. You're asking to use a teaspoon to move a truckload. ORMs are great for working with individual objects. BTW the accepted answer is essentially the same as a `LEFT JOIN` and *exactly* what you should do - load the data into a temp/staging table, then insert the new rows in a single query. You *already* bypassed the ORM and use SQL, as you should

Comment: @AskarIbragimov in fact, this would accelerate MySQL inserts too. `REPLACE` has to check for existence each time, and each operation is fully logged. By inserting everything into a staging table in bulk, you'd get a) far faster loading and b) a far faster JOIN/NOT EXISTS, as the server would be able to use the index and stats on the *staging* table as well, to come up with a good execution plan. And use the server's RAM for buffering as needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 INSERT INTO Table1(IdMarker, Propety1, Property2) 
 SELECT IdMarker
        ,   Property1
        ,   Property2
FROM Table2 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.IdMarker = Table2.Idmarker   )
```